# What is this first-person 3D mobile game shown on TikTok?

Tags: ios, android, game-identification

I saw this game on [@onegameshow's TikTok](https://www.tiktok.com/@onegameshow/video/7046682118646271233) but I couldn’t find it.

[image]

Does anyone know what it’s called?

Answer (score 10):

It appears to be a game called [Flick Master 3D](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.TwoeGames.FlickMaster3D&hl=en_US&gl=US)

[image: Store Image]

Answer (score 8):

It's [Flick Master 3d](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.TwoeGames.FlickMaster3D&hl=en_US&gl=US), the hand and graphics are the same:

[image]